# Why is the Beta function well defined?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis, beta-function

The Euler Beta function is defined by $$B(\alpha, \beta) := \int_0^1 (1-t)^{\alpha -1} t^{\beta -1}dt$$
for $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb C$ with $\Re(\alpha), \Re(\beta) >0$.
I don't see how this is well defined. For example, take $\alpha , \beta = 1/2$. We then have the integrand $(1-t)^{-1/2} t^{-1/2}$ which is not bounded for $t\to0$ nor for $t\to 1$.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: A relevant keyword here is "improper integral."

Comment: $\cdots^{-1/2}$: They are 'integrable singularities'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integrand needn't be bounded.  Note that:

$$0<t<1/2\implies0<(1-t)^{-1/2}t^{-1/2}<\sqrt2t^{-1/2}$$

And further,

$$\underbrace{\int_0^{1/2}t^{-1/2}~\mathrm dt=2t^{1/2}\bigg|_0^{1/2}=\frac1{\sqrt2}}_{\text{Unbounded integrand, but the integral is finite}}$$

Thus, we find that

$$0<\int_0^{1/2}(1-t)^{-1/2}t^{-1/2}~\mathrm dt<1$$

And by symmetry,

$$0<B(1/2,1/2)<2$$

Comment: Stupid me. Thanks.

Comment: @lappen68 No problem, and you're not stupid.  It's good to catch things like the integrand being unbounded, as it could pose a problem.

Comment: Is there a good way to see well-definedness of integrals like these faster/better?

Comment: @lappen68 Generally, see if you can compare it to the following:
$$\int_0^1x^p~\mathrm dx:\text{ Converges for $\Re(p)>-1$, diverges for }\Re(p)\le-1\\\int_1^\infty x^p~\mathrm dx:\text{ Converges for $\Re(p)<-1$, diverges for }\Re(p)\ge-1$$

Comment: Very cool, i've seen these before. I'll keep them in mind. Thank you!